# how to load audio files with js in a carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, audio

I'm trying build a player mp3 in a carousel bootstrap. but only works the first album. the others album not load the audio files, because they are disabled. but how load the audio files when the users do click in navigation buttoms of carousel????. it is better load all audio files when the website load in browser? or with jquery when the item has the class .active?? i am using php and js.

HTML

```
<div id="carousel-mp3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item album1 active">
              <div class="item-list center-block">


            <h3 class="text-center">la desvitualización de las ideas</h3>
                            <img class="img-responsive text-center float" src="images/desvirtualizacion200x200.png">
                            <p class="album-info">ghdfgdfgdfdfggf.</p>
                          <div class="player-mp3">

                                  <table class="table-mp3 center-block" data-directorio-album="ideas" id="reproductor">
                                </tr>

                                <?php

                            $canciones = array(
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Cuando amanece',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!OUNTlQJB!iE524wZy1gBsbmWdguJyVcNVKs4GOdR8RDBR8CVmxRo',
                                    'archivo' => 'amanece.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Escupitajo',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!WJclRZ4b!bIefoNl_qErezMCq3JEj-e1TfhJR1zH2uHZR_fz2mu0',
                                    'archivo' => 'escupitajo.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Estas jodido',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!fEUBnJ5B!PhCUClyw1lVbwdQRm-My4mBhy0-qUObl63iSiVOsvAU',
                                    'archivo' => 'estasjodido.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Esta vida',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!KAUWlSDJ!Y1fPYPz4wcA3Cm55HBydUMOwf8EeuokhZ-ceFj3ZOpA',
                                    'archivo' => 'estavida.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'La valla',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!qAE0kA5Z!rtMxmZsmBPGIvDNmC5WVRF9zxgFbqVVhaXAtMyRmTNQ',
                                    'archivo' => 'lavalla.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Los muertos',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!vB8TABSY!WtLm5dPIM8VEdzi53xY85RFHhqz5-ezdBmLnEG_00wA',
                                    'archivo' => 'losmuertos.mp3',
                                ),
                                    array(
                                    'titulo'  => 'Poemas a la noche',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!nEFXjYqJ!oGOaiRFBeQ4-jZlgHUDAb8XxZKb1QHK_Ivs4KtsuCU0',
                                    'archivo' => 'poemasalanoche.mp3',
                                ),
                            );

                            ?>

                            <?php foreach($canciones as $id => $cancion):?>
                                <tr class="fila">
                                    <td>

                                         <i class="fa fa-play fa-1x icon start" data-id-cancion="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-archivo="<?php echo $cancion['archivo']; ?>">

                                        <span class="track-tittle"> <?php echo $cancion['titulo'] ?></span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                       <time class="seek">00:00</time> / <time class="duration">00:00</time>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cancion['enlace']; ?>">
                                           <i class="fa fa-download get-track fa-1x"></i>
                                           <!--  <img title="Descargar" class="icondes" onmouseover="src='images/downrojo.png'" onmouseout="src='images/downverde.png'"src="images/downverde.png"></a> -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                        </table>
                        <div class="album-download text-center">
                         <a class="buttom-download" href="#">  <i class="fa fa-download fa-cog fa-2x"></i>Descargar Disco</a>
                        </div>
                 </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item album2">
      <div class="item-list center-block">
        <h3 class="text-center">Bokerones muertos</h3>
                            <img class="img-responsive text-center" src="images/bokeronesmuertos200x200.jpg">
                            <p>lorem iumpsuee... </p>
        <div class="player-mp3">
        <table class="table-mp3" data-directorio-album ="bokerones" id="reproductor1">
                            </tr>

                            <?php

                            $canciones1 = array(
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Animal',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!aI1UBQqS!jdusjEJFhRJaL_c-mgtRfEO18ERaANdQI_MucGc_bZs',
                                    'archivo1' => 'animal.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Bokerones muertos',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!iNdnAbYK!72hc7JHN9pM1FCzfYhlG3b9ojvMlrSAOqFKj-Mj-vyk',
                                    'archivo1' => 'bokerones.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Rifeño',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!eAMUjLhZ!1Z16ZJBwlXZggjR2Yua8tphuDvKHkB-zy8WwNKMnoQU',
                                    'archivo1' => 'rifeno.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Sin sentido',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!jYU0WJiY!gqMfUlbVi_TNXlugQlNpAyRC4RZXMwmhGrQrZScAqv4',
                                    'archivo1' => 'sin_sentido.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Soy un hombre',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!uM9B2LoJ!_B5lycWKfkOhGqTP42eShykyd997UsfYr3GvXQ01FLc',
                                    'archivo1' => 'soy_un_hombre.mp3',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'Te quiero',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!fQs0iRSa!jki8C158KGdHXJNMu7eWTJspVROkQoGBv1xPN5G8t0Y',
                                    'archivo1' => 'te_quiero.mp3',
                                ),
                                    array(
                                    'titulo1'  => 'No se ya quien soy',
                                    'enlace'  => 'https://mega.nz/#!iBlhDLRY!k3qvgxzw2odDnB4N7dP6x930g2pFVkaR3O-BJ_IRPDg',
                                    'archivo1' => 'ya_no_se.mp3',
                                ),
                            );
                            ?>

                            <?php foreach($canciones1 as $id => $cancion1):?>
                                <tr class="fila">
                                    <td>
                                        <i class="fa fa-play fa-1x icon start" data-id-cancion="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-archivo="<?php echo $cancion['archivo1']; ?>">
                                        <span class="titulocancion"> <?php echo $cancion1['titulo1'] ?></span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                       <time class="seek">00:00</time> / <time class="duration">00:00</time>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cancion['enlace']; ?>">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");

    var directorioCanciones = 'mp3/';
    var audios = [];
    var directorioAlbum = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor').attr('data-directorio-album') + '/';
    var directorioAlbum1 = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor1').attr('data-directorio-album1') + '/';
    var directorioAlbum2 = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor2').attr('data-directorio-album') + '/';
    var directorioAlbum3 = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor3').attr('data-directorio-album') + '/';
    var directorioAlbum4 = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor4').attr('data-directorio-album') + '/';
    var playingSongId;




//iniciando los audios segun  el item con la clase .active
if($(".album2").hasClass("active"))
{
    var directorioCanciones = 'mp3/';
    var audios = [];
    var directorioAlbum1 = directorioCanciones + $('#reproductor1').attr('data-directorio-album') + '/';
    $.each($('.start'), function(k, audioButton)
    {
        var audio1   = new Audio( directorioAlbum + $(audioButton).attr('data-archivo') );

        var audioId1 = $(audioButton).attr('data-id-cancion');
        audios[audioId1]    = audio1;
         console.log(audio1);
    });

}
    //Inicializando los audios
    $.each($('.start'), function(k, audioButton)
    {
        var audio   = new Audio( directorioAlbum + $(audioButton).attr('data-archivo') );
        //console.log(audio);
        var audioId = $(audioButton).attr('data-id-cancion');
        audios[audioId]    = audio;


        //Mostrando la duracion
        audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            $(audioButton).parents('.fila').find('.duration').text( convierteSegundos(audio.duration) );
        });
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
            $(audioButton).parents('.fila').find('.seek').text( convierteSegundos(audio.currentTime) )
        });
        audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            pauseAndChangeIcon(audioId);
        });
    });
```